# Pods with multiple targets getting error?

Tags: ios, frameworks, cocoapods

Alright, Ive seen this problem in a lot of places but I cant find a clear solution - they all seem to be pretty convoluted. I am trying to add pods to a Message Extension. I get this error when doing the following and running pod install - this happens as soon as opening and trying to run the workspace:

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'LaunchPack' do
  # Comment this line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for LaunchPack
pod 'lottie-ios'

end

target 'MessagesExtension' do
  # Comment this line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for MessagesExtension
pod 'lottie-ios'

end
```

Here I pod to both targets and per solutions like https://www.bountysource.com/issues/35748866-missing-embed-pods-build-phase-for-messages-extension-target I have manually added the library (Lottie) to the Link Binaries with Libraries section of BOTH targets:

[image]

The link above describes "The issue can be fixed by ensuring that the framework is weakly linked and manually adding a "Run Script" build phase for the -frameworks.sh script"

however I don't understand what they mean by that. Where I can I link the framework other than where I have already?

How can I add pods to my MessageExtension?

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue when adding pods for multiple targets what I did was uninstalled and deleted all the pods file first. Then create multiple targets and after that add the pod file and installed it and works fine for me.

Comment: I dont know how this would apply here - started out with the base message extension setup, meaning multiple targets were always there to start. I just did pod init on this project, and then came the errors. I don't even need multiple targets just the message extension - what can I do?

Comment: Have you tried deleting the pod file, uninstalling it  and then install it freshly?